# SQL structure for holding arrays?

Tags: php, sql, multidimensional-array

How can I relate a table with multiple records from another table?

Basically, I have a table for an 'event', how do I keep track of which 'users' (in their own seperate table) are in a particular event? Right now I just have a column in the 'event' table with a comma separated list of the users IDs who have joined that 'event'.

There must be a better way to do this...right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you have a table called `users_in_event` which holds one row for each user in a many-to-many relationship with the `events` table.  So for each event, you will have a number of table rows mapped individually to users.

```
CREATE TABLE users_in_event
( 
  user_id INT,
  event_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY user_id REFERENCES users (user_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,       
  FOREIGN KEY event_id REFERENCES events (event_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
  -- Optionally, use ON DELETE CASCADE for the events foreign key
  -- FOREIGN KEY event_id REFERENCES events (event_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

To find out which users are in an event, do:

```
SELECT 
  users_in_event.user_id,
  users.name
FROM users JOIN users_in_event ON users.user_id = users_in_event.user_id
WHERE event_id=1234;
```

Comment: Your SQL is a better, more complete example, but it's worth noting that it's a many-to-many relationship, not one-to-many. If it was one-to-many, then one event could have many users, but each user could only ever attend one event, in which case a more direct way to represent the relationship is to put a field on the "many" side, e.g., one event has many users, so the `users` table would have an `event_id` column.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a many-to-many relationship, that is, users can attend many events, and events can be attended by many users, that would traditionally be represented with a mapping table with the primary key from each table, plus any attributes specific to the user-event relationship.

For example, if you have ID columns in your `USER` and `EVENT` tables that are both type `INT`:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_EVENT_MAPPING
(
    USER_ID INT,
    EVENT_ID INT
)
```